# pdf js cant load worker

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Im trying to render pdf using pdfjs. Its working but im getting 404 with loading the script: [image]

I am calling pdf js in this manner:

```
import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';

  pdfCreator: any = PDFJS;
 this.pdfCreator
      .getDocument(url)
      .then((doc) => {
        this.doc = doc;
        console.log('pdf2')

        this.renderPages(canvasContainer, scale);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

[image]

Is the import wrong or I should add worker.js manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following import the worker and assign it to GlobalWorkerOptions

```
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
import pdfWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/lib/pdf.worker';

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfWorker;

pdfjsLib.getDocument(src).then(pdf => {
//add your code here
});
```